# Getting the value of a variable based on a string name in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a Java application in which I need to read a String instance variable and upon encountering a value between two $ signs, i.e $sample$, replace it with the appropriate value.

The "sample" part corresponds to the name of one of several other instance variables in my code, so what I need to do is extract the "sample" as a String and then somehow use it to get the value of the instance variable called sample.
Is there any way I can do this other than using some predefined key, value pairs of a hashmap?

Comment: Please mention expected input and required output!

Comment: replaceAll + regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection and a helper method for this:

```
public static Object getFieldValue(Object target, String fieldName){
    // get field from class
    Field field = target.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);

    // set accessability to "public"
    field.setAccessible(true);
    try{
        // get value
        return field.get(target);
    } catch(IllegalAccessException e){
        // or throw error
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

This can then be invoked easily with:

```
Object value = getFieldValue(this, "sample");
```

The snippet uses [`Class#getDeclaredField(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField-java.lang.String-) as suggested by @aszro in the comments. This method returns the field by name or throws a `NoSuchElementException` if no field exists.

Comment: Can directly use `getDeclaredField(String name)` instead of loop+if  > [Doc link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField-java.lang.String-)